# FastAPI Startup/Shutdown Events

Tags: python, fastapi

Copied & pasted:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

items = {}

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    items["foo"] = {"name": "Fighters"}
    items["bar"] = {"name": "Tenders"}

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_items(item_id: str):
    return items[item_id]
```

from https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/. Getting error:

```
    @app.on_event("startup")
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: FastAPI.on_event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event_type'
```

Comment: Okay, so what's the question?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, I ran the code and it works.